# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UITextView text update

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have a problem, randomly I'm getting a weird crash on my app, I have no idea why.. the textfield is allocated like this

```
[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Could anyone help me fix this, or at least tell me what is wrong? What I read on the internet is that I am trying to access a pointer that is gone and the app crashes.

[image: weird crash]

The method

```
- (void)setText:(NSString*)text textView:(UITextView*)textView{
    if (textView != nil) {


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([textView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                textView.text = text;
                CGSize textViewSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
                textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x,
                                            textView.frame.origin.y,
                                            textView.contentSize.width,
                                            textViewSize.height);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code around the crash please?

Comment: Could you show the part of the code where it's set? Since you are using a `dispatch_etc`, you may need to set before `__block`.

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: text is a NSString